# Date parameters in query

Tags: ms-access

I have a form with which I enter data. A sort order, start date and end date.

Once the data is entered, a report is generated. But I get and error.

Error: "The Microsoft Access database engine does not recognize '[Forms]![AuditPTETotals]![startDate]' as a valid field name or expression.

This is my crosstab (AuditPTETotals_CrosstabDateRange) query which uses the data retrieved by another query (AuditPTETotalsDateRange)

```
TRANSFORM Sum(AuditPTETotalsDateRange.PTEtotal) AS SumOfPTEtotal
SELECT AuditPTETotalsDateRange.companyName, AuditPTETotalsDateRange.regNum,    Sum(AuditPTETotalsDateRange.PTEtotal) AS [Total Of PTEtotal]
FROM AuditPTETotalsDateRange
GROUP BY AuditPTETotalsDateRange.companyName, AuditPTETotalsDateRange.regNum
PIVOT AuditPTETotalsDateRange.description;
```

And this is AuditPTETotalsDateRange

```
    SELECT CUSTOMER.regNum, CUSTOMER.companyName, ScrapTireType.description, ScrapTireType.PTEamount, ScrapCollectionTireType.amount, ScrapCollection.PTEtotal, ScrapCollection.Date
FROM (ScrapCollection INNER JOIN CUSTOMER ON ScrapCollection.regNum = CUSTOMER.regNum) INNER JOIN (ScrapTireType INNER JOIN ScrapCollectionTireType ON (ScrapTireType.scrapTireTypeID = ScrapCollectionTireType.scrapTireTypeID) AND (ScrapTireType.scrapTireTypeID = ScrapCollectionTireType.scrapTireTypeID)) ON ScrapCollection.scrapCollectionID = ScrapCollectionTireType.scrapCollectionID
WHERE (((ScrapCollection.Date) Between [Forms]![AuditPTETotals]![startDate] And [Forms]![AuditPTETotals]![endDate]));
```

I have used this approach in a similar way to reference forms fields in a query but this time, I am not sure what I'm doing wrong. Please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution! I was using a Date/Time format on my controls. I think it was messing up with the actual format of my parameters. Instead I used a regular text box and set an input mask to it. It worked.

Comment: Found another solution, I was using short date instead of a general date. I changed this and It worked as well.

Answer (score 0):

Create a button on the form that you are working with and add the below to its Click event.  Make sure to change the **MyReportName** to the actual reports name.  **MyReportName** appears twice in the below code.

```
On Error Resume Next
DoCmd.Close acReport, "MyReportName"
DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "AuditPTETotalsDateRange"
On Error GoTo Err_cmd_Click

Dim strSQL, strSQL1 As String
Dim qdef As DAO.QueryDef

strSQL = "SELECT CUSTOMER.regNum, CUSTOMER.companyName, ScrapTireType.description, ScrapTireType.PTEamount, ScrapCollectionTireType.amount, ScrapCollection.PTEtotal, ScrapCollection.Date " & _
         "FROM (ScrapCollection INNER JOIN CUSTOMER ON ScrapCollection.regNum = CUSTOMER.regNum) INNER JOIN (ScrapTireType INNER JOIN ScrapCollectionTireType ON (ScrapTireType.scrapTireTypeID = ScrapCollectionTireType.scrapTireTypeID) AND (ScrapTireType.scrapTireTypeID = ScrapCollectionTireType.scrapTireTypeID)) ON ScrapCollection.scrapCollectionID = ScrapCollectionTireType.scrapCollectionID " & _
         "WHERE (((ScrapCollection.Date) Between #" & [Forms]![AuditPTETotals]![startDate] & "# And #" & [Forms]![AuditPTETotals]![endDate] & "#))"

strSQL1 = "TRANSFORM Sum(AuditPTETotalsDateRange.PTEtotal) AS SumOfPTEtotal " & _
          "SELECT AuditPTETotalsDateRange.companyName, AuditPTETotalsDateRange.regNum, Sum(AuditPTETotalsDateRange.PTEtotal) AS [Total Of PTEtotal] " & _
          "FROM AuditPTETotalsDateRange " & _
          "GROUP BY AuditPTETotalsDateRange.companyName, AuditPTETotalsDateRange.regNum " & _
          "PIVOT AuditPTETotalsDateRange.description"

Set qdef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("AuditPTETotalsDateRange", strSQL)
Set qdef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("AuditPTETotals_CrosstabDateRange", strSQL1)
DoCmd.OpenReport "MyReportName", acViewPreview

Exit_cmd_Click:
    Exit Sub
Err_cmd_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_cmd_Click
```

Then on the forms On Close event add the following:

```
On Error Resume Next
DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "AuditPTETotalsDateRange"
```

What happens then is if the button is clicked the AuditPTETotalsDateRange is deleted and then recreated.  Also, if you close the form the AuditPTETotalsDateRange query is deleted.  Which is ok since the query is only needed when the form is open anyway. Set the record source of the report to AuditPTETotals_CrosstabDateRange.

You will have to have a reference to **Microsoft DAO x.x Object Library** set in order for the above code to work.  You may already have the reference set.  The x.x represents the version.  Any version should work.

**EDIT**

You may want to copy the original report before making all these changes just incase it doesn't work for you.  Try removing the data source from the fields on the report so they are unbound. Then add the following code to the report on open event:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("AuditPTETotals_CrosstabDateRange", dbOpenDynaset)

On Error Resume Next
[txtdata1].ControlSource = rs.Fields(4).Name
[txtData2].ControlSource = rs.Fields(5).Name
[txtData3].ControlSource = rs.Fields(6).Name
//And etc for as many fields as you have on report
```

You can also assign the column headings on the page header in a similar fashion.  They will need to changed from a label to a textbox that is unbound in order for it to work.  Add the following code to the page header On Format event:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("AuditPTETotals_CrosstabDateRange", dbOpenDynaset)

On Error Resume Next
[txtColHeading1].value = rs.Fields(4).Name
[txtColHeading2].value = rs.Fields(5).Name
[txtColHeading3].value = rs.Fields(6).Name
//And etc for as many fields as you have on report
```

This will allow your report to run without ever knowing for sure what columns you are going to have.  Make sure you name your controls to match the names here in the code or vice versa.

Comment: I created the query with the query wizard and set it as the record source for my report. I tried with the "#" but still no luck. I've tried to execute the query through the VBA but I need that query to exist at all time in order for the cross tab query to work.

Comment: I modified my answer to show how to create/delete the query within the form you are using.

Comment: I don't get the error anymore although It seems to timeout. I haven't referenced the DAO object library yet so that might be why but I just put at the top of my code or?

Comment: The message is "This action will reset the current code in break mode"

Comment: I am currently using this code in my report_open event. I of course modified it but would that bring up any issues? I'm super new to access and this is a work term project so I'm a little lost. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: The code I have provided above should be ran from a form.  The only thing your report needs to have is the transform statement as its record source.

Comment: Yup it has that. I'll give you a little background how my form and report interact. My form consists of 3 fields (Sort order, start date and end date) once the user has selected from the above fields, they press the "View Report" button which calls a macro which opens a different report based on the sorting order. My record source for my report is set on the open event of the report itself. I think I'm going to move the code to my form instead of the report.

Comment: Alright I moved the code to the form but now I get this "The Microsoft Access database engine does not recognize 'Agricultural' as a valid field name or expression". It's weird because I am  not referencing Agricultural in this report at all. There is a field in my report named "Agricultural" but that is it.

Comment: Remove that field from the report momentarily and see if it will run.

Comment: Okay it is doing what I thought it would. This time the error comes up for the ATV field which is right after the Agricultural. Those fields are from my crosstab query and they are listed horizontally.

Comment: Agricultural and ATV are not a pat of the cross tab query.  The only fields that you will have available to your report based on the cross tab query are the following: **companyName**,  **regNum**, and **Total Of PTEtotal**.  If you want Agricultural and ATV then add them to your SELECT and also GROUP BY of your cross tab query

Comment: Actually ignore the last comment I had.  Your PIVOT is on description.  Those fields are created if they are a part of the query.  If you run the query are those columns created?  If not there was not any data for that given description.

Comment: Yup those columns are created and display data.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the data the query returns as well as a screenshot of your report in design view.  Maybe I can spot what the problem is. [imgur](http://imgur.com/) is a good place to upload images then just add the link here.

Comment: Here you are. You will not see any company names in the query though. I had to omit them for privacy reasons. http://imgur.com/jzdfJ,czuE5#0

Comment: Try the above change to the report to dynamically name the fields.  Maybe it will help.